# Update Corrupted GRUB; Can't Boot Right

Tags: linux

Okay, I've been trying to repair my GRUB for awhile on my version of Lubuntu 14, and nothing seems to work.

It seems that an update has broken my GRUB, so that now when I try to boot on the computer, it only takes me to a black screen where I can type, but none of the inputs do anything.

After resetting it once or twice, it takes me a screen of options, where I select recovery mode, and then from the recovery mode menu to boot normally, which does indeed make it boot normally.

I tried Boot Repair twice, and it said it works, but nay. I actually got two separate paste messages too after each attempted repair.

I'm not sure if anyone will care for the first, but here's the second: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8503260 .

What should I do?

Comment: Do you happen to know your kernel image name, initrd image name and the root partition name? If yes, then you should be able to edit it from grub prompt and boot the system.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling grub ?  

`$ sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` (replace sdX with your hd)   
`$ sudo update-grub`

Comment: Try this also `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: @Sree I not that knowledgeable about Linux, so I don't know any of that terminology right now.

Comment: @lemonsqueeze I tried your first terminal command, but it said it wouldn't do it for some reason, and warned me against something called "blocklists." I tried your other command, then, but a reboot shows it hasn't worked.

Comment: @lemonsqueeze Actually, I'm silly. I tried reinstalling again after realizing I mistyped the hard drive. It went through, but once again a reboot shows it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have a similar machine anywhere else? Can you copy the contents of the grub.conf here?

Comment: @Sree I am able to copy the contents of grub.cfg, if that's the relevant file (no grub.conf), but how shall I copy it here? It's too long for a comment and will make my original problem post way too big.

Comment: @Benjamin what do you see on the black screen when it starts?  Is it `grub rescue>`?